# How do I filter a string object based on the partial string matches in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, checkbox

I have a string object with values:

```
dictionary={ 
 1: ["a1+b+c"],
 2: ["a1+c+v"], 
 3: ["a1+z+e"], 
 4: ["a2+p+a"], 
 5: ["a2+z+v"], 
 6: ["a3+q+v"], 
 ...};
```

I have a page with checkboxes for each partial string value in an object, e.g. checkboxes "a","b","c",... etc. On the page, the checkboxes are located in groups a1, a2, a3, etc.

```
      <p><div id="displayString">
      </div></p>


<table>
         <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>a1</th>
              <th>a2</th>
              <th>a3</th> 
              <th>a4</th>
              <th>a5</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="a" class="a1" />a</label></td>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="a" class="a2" />a</label></td>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="a" class="a3" />a</label></td>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="a" class="a4" />a</label></td>
             <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="a" class="a5" />a</label></td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="b" class="a1" />b</label></td>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="b" class="a2" />b</label></td>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="b" class="a3" />b</label></td>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="b" class="a4" />b</label></td>
             <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="b" class="a5" />b</label></td>
              </tr>
      ...
```

I need to filter the dictionary by the partial values based on the values of the selected checkboxes, for example, when selecting "c" in group a1, it would return:

```
 1: a1+b+c
 2: a1+c+v
```

When selecting "z" from group a2, it would return:

```
 5: "a2+z+v"
```

The code I have (a function for each group) is:

```
$(function(){
$(".a1").on("click", function(){
  var arr = $(".a1:checked").map(function(){
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();
  $('#displayString').html(arr);  
})
})
```

This code only shows the values selected. What is a way to create a partial lookup and list all matches one under the other?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Does this help you?

So essentially, we are searching the dictionary elements based on the values of the checkboxes using the `join`, `filter` and `map` methods to find valid matches.

We can also do the same thing using `reduce`, but it would be harder to explain, I thought.

First, we split the strings using the `split` method. So `a1+b+v` becomes ['a1','b','v']. This is a necessary step because if we just search directly within the string without splitting, `a1` `a` will match the string. Because both of those are present in the string. Instead we split them up and do an exact match. So only `a1` and `b` will match the said string.

Then, we use the indices of those matches and get the original strings in the last step. Hope it helped you.

```js
var dictionary=[
  "a1+b+c",
  "a1+c+v", 
  "a1+z+e", 
  "a2+p+a", 
  "a2+z+v", 
  "a3+q+v", 
 ];
 
var splitDictionary = dictionary.map(item => item.split("+"))

$("#my-table [type='checkbox']").change(function(){
  if(this.checked){
     const value = this.value;
     const className = $(this).attr('class');
     const filteredDictionary = splitDictionary.map((item,index) => item.includes(value) && item.includes(className) ? index : null);
     const values = filteredDictionary.filter(item => item !== null).map(index => dictionary[index]);
    console.log(values);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped" id="my-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>a1</th>
              <th>a2</th>
              <th>a3</th> 
              <th>a4</th>
              <th>a5</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="a" class="a1" />a</label></td>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="a" class="a2" />a</label></td>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="a" class="a3" />a</label></td>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="a" class="a4" />a</label></td>
             <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="a" class="a5" />a</label></td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="b" class="a1" />b</label></td>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="b" class="a2" />b</label></td>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="b" class="a3" />b</label></td>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="b" class="a4" />b</label></td>
             <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="b" class="a5" />b</label></td>
              </tr>
            
                        <tr>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="c" class="a1" />c</label></td>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="c" class="a2" />c</label></td>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="c" class="a3" />c</label></td>
              <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="c" class="a4" />c</label></td>
             <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="c" class="a5" />c</label></td>
              </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```